LilyPond: Clair de Lune challenge
Clair de Lune is strange. Its poetry extends impressionism not only to the audial sensation but also to the visual perception of engraving. Wait... didn't impressionism start from the visual? Well, anyway, the very first bar is challenging:

You can see that 1/8th is sort of missing in the left hand. The impressionistic logic of it is that the right-hand 1/8th occupies that missing spot.
In technical terms, it means I have to tie two chords in the left hand over a skipped 1/8th. Roughly, something like this:
\version "2.24.0"

\language "italiano"

cu = { \change Staff = "right" }
cd = { \change Staff = "left" }

global = {
    \key reb \major
    \time 9/8
}

right = \new Staff = "right" {
    \relative do'' {
        \global
        r8 r8
    }
}
left = \new Staff = "left" {
    \relative do' {
        \global
        r8 <fa lab>~ \cu <fa' lab> \cd <fa, lab>2.
    }
}

\new PianoStaff {
    <<
        \right
        \left
    >>
}

Well, a nice try, but this doesn't work. LilyPond complains that the tie hasn't been terminated.
So, how can one engrave the bar in the picture above?

The reason for your error is that tie will expect the tied note to be next. You’d need to set tieWaitForNote to #t. But then I would suggest to notate this more or less in this manner (actually encoding the two voices):
\new PianoStaff <<
  \new Staff = "up" { r8 r }
  \new Staff = "down" {
    r8
    <<
      \new Voice {
        \voiceOne
        <f' as'>
        \oneVoice\change Staff = "up" <f'' as''>~ q4. <des'' f''>
      }
      {
        \once\hideNotes <f' as'>4~
        q2.
      }
    >>
  }
>>


What's the difference between <<\new Voice {} {}>> and <<{} \\ {}>>? The documentation says something about the "Bottom" context. And the "Bottom" context is the one without defaultchild.  Can it be explained in English?

<<{}\\{}>> creates two new voices whereas <<\new Voice{}{}>> creates only one new voice.  The second set of braces can be thought of as a continuation of the outside context.

@facetus << ... >> has no context by itself. It only means to align the content in parallel. \new Voice creates a new voice context. If we do {... \new Voice ... } this does not change a lot, as you create a new Voice and do not do anything in the old voice. But if you do << ... \new Voice ... >>you tell Lilypond to create a new Voice in parallel to what’s currently going on.\is a special syntax which will essentially evaluate<< ... \ ... >>to<< \new Voice { \voiceOne ... } \new Voice { \voiceTwo ...} >>`.

@facetus ... Now, this is useful for quickly creating polyphony. The problem is that by default beams, Slurs, Ties, ... need to stay in one Voice. So for more complex things like this it is useful to manually control where new Voices are created and where you stay within one Voice.

Thank you, guys!
